# Converting a factor to numeric in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I know that variations of this question have been asked and answered, but I can't seem to get any to work for me.

I have a column labeled 'Interest.Rate', and the values are of this form: 12.75%

I tried:

```
as.numeric(as.character(loansData$Interest.Rate))
```

And what I got back was a screen full of 'NA's.

I suspect that I need to remove the '%' sign, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You're right, you need to remove  the '%' sign and then coerce the result to be numeric

```
> set.seed(1)
> Interest.Rate <- as.factor(paste0(sample(10), "%"))
> as.numeric(as.character(Interest.Rate))  # problem!!
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

> as.numeric(gsub("\\%", "", Interest.Rate))  # solution
 [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
```

Comment: Same tool, different flavor: `loansData$Interest.Rate <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "",loansData$Interest.Rate))`

Comment: @ChelseaE, not if there are decimals as in the original post. Your "flavor" would strip the decimals out.

Comment: Woops! You are completely correct @AnandaMahto, the right code should read `loansData$Interest.Rate <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9\\.]", "",loansData$Interest.Rate))`, thank you for your correction!